# Incomplete line-plotting

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph, line

I am working on an app that plots a graph based on the input from the user. However when I try plotting the graph, the line doesn't go all the way.

The code is below:

```
    v = text_v.get()
    i = text_i.get()
    v2 = v.split(", ")
    i2 = i.split(", ")
    outcome = True

    #Testing for pairing of values
    if range(len(v2)) != range(len(i2)):
        tkm.showerror("Incomplete values", "You did not enter an equal number of voltage and resistance values")
        outcome = False

    #Testing for v-value type
    for x in range(len(v2)):
        try:
            float(v2[x])
            outcome = True
        except:
            tkm.showerror("Wrong value type", "All your voltage values must be floats or integers")
            outcome = False
            break

    #Testing for i-value type
    for x in range(len(i2)):
        try:
            float(i2[x])
        except:
            tkm.showerror("Wrong value type", "All your current values must be floats or integers")
            outcome = False
            break

    #------------------------Graph plotting function----------------------------
    if outcome == True:
        v = np.array(list(map(float, v.split(", "))))
        i = np.array(list(map(float, i.split(", "))))
        fit = np.polyfit(i,v,1)
        fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit) 
        plt.plot(i,v, 'bo', v, fit_fn(v), '--k')
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the ques.. can u fix the code?